# -Python- Ordering lists based on a format

Tags: python, list

I'm new to programming in general, so looking to really expand my skills here. I'm trying to write a script that will grab a list of strings from an object, then order them based on a template of my design. Any items not in the template will be added to the end.

Here's how I'm doing it now, but could someone suggest a better/more efficient way?

```
    originalList = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'z', 'd']
    listTemplate = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    listFinal = []

    for thing in listTemplate:
        if thing in originalList:
            listFinal.append(thing)
            originalList.pop(originalList.index(thing))

    for thing in originalList:
            listFinal.append(thing)
            originalList.pop(originalList.index(thing))
```

Comment: You've done a good job. Perhaps someone knows a more efficient way though...

Comment: It may not apply to your use case, but just so you know, if `originalList` contains only unique elements, `set(listTemplate + originalList)` could do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
originalList = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'z', 'd']
listTemplate = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

order = { element:index for index, element in enumerate(listTemplate) }
sorted(originalList, key=lambda element: order.get(element, float('+inf')))

=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
```

This is how it works:

- First, we build a dictionary indicating, for each element in `listTemplate`, its relative order with respect to the others. For example `a` is `0`, `b` is `1` and so on
- Then we sort `originalList`. If one of its elements is present in the `order` dictionary, then use its relative position for ordering. If it's not present, return a positive infinite value - this will guarantee that the elements not in `listTemplate` will end up at the end, with no further ordering among them.

The solution in the question, although correct, is not very pythonic. In particular, whenever you have to build a new list, try to use a list comprehension instead of explicit looping/appending. And it's not a good practice to "destroy" the input list (using `pop()` in this case).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary amazing that we came up with the same answer! I'll leave mine around for a while, in case someone finds the explanation useful, otherwise I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict using the `listTemplate` list, that way the expensive(`O(N)`) `list.index` operations can be reduced to `O(1)` lookups.

```
>>> lis1 = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'z', 'd']
>>> lis2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Use `enumerate` to create a dict with the items as keys(Considering that the items are hashable) and index as values.

```
>>> dic = { x:i for i,x in enumerate(lis2) }
```

Now `dic` looks like:

```
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 3}
```

Now for each item in `lis1` we need to check it's index in dic, if the key is not found we return `float('inf')`.

Function used as `key`:

```
def get_index(key):
   return dic.get(key, float('inf'))
```

Now sort the list:

```
>>> lis1.sort(key=get_index)
>>> lis1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
```

Comment: @Joowani Yes it is, but the overall complexity is still `O(NlogN)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the final step, you can just use:

```
listFinal += originalList
```

and it will add these items to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that has better computational complexity:

```
# add all elements of originalList not found in listTemplate to the back of listTemplate
s = set(listTemplate)
listTemplate.extend(el for el in originalList if el not in s)

# now sort
rank = {el:index for index,el in enumerate(listTemplate)}
listFinal = sorted(originalList, key=rank.get)
```

Comment: In the final line, it's shorter to say `key=rank.get`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new dictionary at all:

```
>>> len_lis1=len(lis1)

>>> lis1.sort(key = lambda x: lis2.index(x) if x in lis2 else len_lis1)

>>> lis1
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
```

Comment: Do you've any idea about the complexity of this solution?